# Update Entity properties via FetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I made an application which is collecting user bills and payments. But it didn't have "Edit" property so I want to update my app with "Edit" property.

I have an tableviewcontroller which is listing user all payments. If user click the cell app goes "Detail Payment" view controller.

First of all there is my Add Payment View Controller prepare for segue codes ;

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addKredi"]) {

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [segue destinationViewController];

    ESMAddKrediViewController *addKrediViewController = (ESMAddKrediViewController *) navigationController.topViewController;

    Kredi *addKredi = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Kredi" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

    Odeme *addKrediToOdeme = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Odeme" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

    addKrediViewController.addKredi = addKredi;

    addKrediViewController.addKrediToOdeme = addKrediToOdeme;
}
```

There is the Add Credit View Controller codes;

```
 static NSString *kategoriKredi = @"Banka Kredilerim";
_addKredi.krediAdi = _txtKrediAdi.text; //Kredi Entity
_addKrediToOdeme.odemeAdi = _txtKrediAdi.text; //Odeme Entity
_addKrediToOdeme.kategori = kategoriKredi;
```

My tableviewcontroller fetches user all payments via "Odeme" entity.

There is my tableviewcontroller codes to Detail ViewController ;

if user select the Credit type payment (Kredi) my app checks category with those codes and sending some info to Detail View Controller ;

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Odeme *odeme = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([odeme.kategori isEqualToString:@"Kredi Kartlarım"]){

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toTaksitler" sender:nil];
}

if ([odeme.kategori isEqualToString:@"Faturalarım"]){

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toFaturaDetay" sender:nil];
}

if ([odeme.kategori isEqualToString:@"Banka Kredilerim"]){

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toKrediDetay" sender:nil];
}
```

**I send odemeAdi to krediViewController.krediAdi**

```
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toKrediDetay"]) {


    ESMKrediViewController *krediViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    Odeme *selectedKredi = (Odeme *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    krediViewController.odendi = selectedKredi.odendi;

    krediViewController.krediAdi = selectedKredi.odemeAdi;

    krediViewController.selectedKredi = selectedKredi;

    krediViewController.navigationItem.title = selectedKredi.odemeAdi;


}
```

I can catch the name of Credit and I fetch credit Details in my Detail ViewController with those codes ; (In CreditDetailViewController)

```
#pragma mark - Fetched Results Controller Section

-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController{

if (_fetchedResultsController !=nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Kredi" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"krediAdi" ascending:YES];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"krediAdi == %@ ",krediAdi];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

And my app can show all properties about selected Credit via this way.I tried to explain all my codes.But I know its complicated question and my English is not enough to explain clearly. But maybe someone can read the codes and help this desperate guy.

So there is my question.

I want to edit Credit Detail View Controller. How can i change Kredi entity properties like krediAdi ?

I fetched all Kredi Entity properties in this detail View Controller but i can't update or override properties. I stuck there.

Comment: you don't fetch properties, you fetch objects that have properties, and you should be able to edit them

Comment: I fetched them to NSArray with this code ; 
    NSArray *array = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;
but if i change array objects, core data will not effect.I have to change core data Entity properties because i fetch the objects  via core data. How can i change ?

Comment: can someone help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this code ;

```
[[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]objectAtIndex:0]setBorcAdi:self.txtBorcAdi.text];
```

BorcAdi is a Borclar entity's property.

You can edit or change the entity properties with this code.

Note:I used Predicate and i get only 1 result so i can reach it with objectAtIndex:0.